# Copying Worksheet into another folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code to copy sheet8 from workbook with the name xyz.xlsx present in cell P2 of sheet1 and paste it in another folder folderX. I have not written the paste-code till now.

I am getting:

> Runtime error '424' Object required

The snippet of the code:

```
Sub file_name()
returnVal = Sheet1.Cells(2, 16).Value
Dim FPath As String
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheet8.Copy
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=returnVal & “.xlsx”
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am very new to macros.

Comment: `FileName:=FPath  & "\" & returnVal & ".xlsx"` And if `Sheet1.Cells(2, 16).Value` has something like "xyz.xlsx" then use `FileName:=FPath  & "\" & returnVal`

Comment: Please put `Option Explicit` on top.

Comment: @SiddharthRout its giving Run-time error '1004' Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed. Thank you for previous answer.

Comment: Debug and see what is the value of `FPath & "\" & returnVal` Also you will have to specify the FileFormat

Comment: It is giving the correct path (same path of the initial file) and returnVal is also correct. How to specify the FileFormat? ".xlsx"

Comment: I have posted an answer. See if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

**My Assumptions:**

1. I am assuming that cell `P2` of `Sheet1` has a value like `xyz.xlsx`.
2. I am assuming that the workbook from where you are running the code is saved (at least once to get the correct value of `FPath`).
3. I am assuming that you have `Sheet8`

**Code:**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub file_name()
    Dim ScrnUpdating As Boolean
    Dim DispAlerts As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    With Application
        '~~> Store existing settings before changing
        ScrnUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
        DispAlerts = .DisplayAlerts

        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Dim returnVal As String
    returnVal = Sheet1.Cells(2, 16).Value

    Dim FPath As String
    FPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    Sheet8.Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & returnVal, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

LetsContinue:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = ScrnUpdating
        .DisplayAlerts = DispAlerts
    End With

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry for bothering but now it's showing, 'Compile error: variable not defined'. 
This is the thing I am trying to do. The P2 does not contain {xyz.xlsx} but xyz only for which I added {FPath & "\" & returnVal & ".xlsx"} to Filename

Comment: `variable not defined` That means you have not declared the variable. `FPath & "\" & returnVal & ".xlsx"` is fine if P2 does not contain {xyz.xlsx}. Which line are you getting the error? My code is tried and tested. you shouldn't be getting any error